# How to pull a CSV file from a website using a Java application?

Tags: java, csv

So I have a problem. I want to design a program which pulls a CSV file from a certain website automatically. The thing is, I have no idea how to do so. It seems that the button which is used to download the CSV file doesn't actually point that file, but rather points to a function that does its thing and returns a CSV file. How can I pull this CSV file from the website? Apparently this has something to do with a servlet but I'm not quite sure. Thanks

Edit: It seems that there isn't really a link like bla.com/.../myfile.csv but rather bla.com/.../getReport.do and regardless of what I input into the text boxes which are provided on the website, the link stays as bla.com/.../getReport.do. The problem I have is that I can't just use the standard IO libraries in Java to download the csv file because I have no idea how to actually get the file without manually downloading it.

Comment: You question is extremely vague - without more information it's impossible to help you...

Comment: Like @assylias said, your question is vague.  Are you designing a program in Java EE, Java SE, etc., and are you trying to create a button that saves a .csv file at a set interval?  You'll need to do some research on MIME types and check what MIME type you would need to return. See this article for an example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725795/mime-type-content-type-for-opening-csv-files-using-excel-in-ie-firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use Chrome.
2. Press F12 to get the developer window - look at the network tab.
3. Download your csv and watch for the file that you want in the panel.
4. Right-click on your CSV file in the network tab you should be able
   to copy as cURL
   [image]
5. you can paste that command into a CMD prompt (on windows) or a bash terminal (in Linux or Mac).
6. On Linux set up a cron job to fire off that command regularly.

To send the output to a file... add **>file.txt** to the end of the command.

curl 'http://app.toronto.ca/tmmis/getAdminReport.do' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Referer: http://app.toronto.ca/tmmis/getAdminReport.do' -H 'Origin: http://app.toronto.ca' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --data 'function=getMemberVoteReport&download=csv&page=0&itemsPerPage=50&sortBy=&sortOrder=&exportPublishReportId=2&termId=6&memberId=2&decisionBodyId=0&fromDate=2014-12-31&toDate=2016-05-10' --compressed **> file1.txt**

Comment: Okay so I'm definitely making progress with this post. When I pasted the cURL into my terminal, it gave me some crazy text. After the curl '(link)' I got some text saying 'Cookie: WEBTRENDS_ID=38.99.162.133.1462801305877877; JSESSIONID=0000ckiWeKMpaPRWtcWHGXp9_Rj:199aa9lg1; __atuvc=30%7C19; WT_FPC=id=38.99.162.133-1250814704.30518001:lv=1462905070843:ss=1462904525624'


What should I do with all this? Again the problem I have is that the link doesn't end with a /myfile.csv but rather with a function call

Comment: http://app.toronto.ca/tmmis/getAdminReport.do?function=prepareMemberVoteReport

The csv I want is in the "Download all available vote records for the 2014-2018 term" text

Comment: Not a problem that the end of the url is a program - it makes no difference to curl. You can output to any filename you like.